# Chunked HTTP Post Request: Arduino/telnet

Tags: c, bash, arduino, telnet

This is what my chunked POST request looks like. I am trying to send chunks of data from an SD card on the arduino to a server through a chunked POST request. Need chunked as it will allow me to send the data which will not all fit into the arduino's memory at once.

```
POST /upload HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Arduino
Host: ooboontoo
Accept: */*
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

25
this is the text, of this file, wooo!
1d
more test, of this file
0
```

However I am getting an error when the server tries parsing the request:

> {"25\r\nthis is the text, of this file, wooo!\r\n"=>nil} Invalid
>   request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.

I tried reading the chunked requests documentation but it appears there are multiple ways of doing the same thing so I am a bit confused on what is *the* correct way.

Any advice would be appreciated thanks!

EDIT:

here is the bash code I wrote to output the above request to telnet
run with: ./testit.sh | telnet

```
#! /bin/bash
#testit.sh
#Arduino Telnet HTTP POST tests

header="POST /upload HTTP/1.1\n"
header+="User-Agent: Arduino\n"
header+="Host: localhost 3000\n"
header+="Accept: */*\n"
header+="Transfer-Encoding: chunked\n"

thisfile="this is the text, of this file"
thisfilelen=${#thisfile}
printf -v hexlen '%x' $thisfilelen
thisfile2="more test, of this file"
thisfilelen2=${#thisfile2}
printf -v hexlen2 '%x' $thisfilelen2
end="0"


echo "open localhost 3000"
sleep 2
echo -e $header
echo -e $hexlen
echo -e $thisfile
echo -e $hexlen2
echo -e $thisfile2
echo -e $end
sleep 2
```

Comment: Also:
non-chunked POST requests are going through fine so it must be something wrong with the syntax of this request

Comment: An interesting problem, but on Stack Overflow, we help people with their code. You have tagged this with `c` and `bash`, but haven't shown any code. We're not mindreaders, so show us what you are doing, and maybe we can help with your problem. Good luck.

Comment: I was trying to keep the problem technology-independent by specifically *not* showing the code that creates the POST request and only showing the request that is sent to the server. Whether I use echo "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" or client.println("POST /upload HTTP/1.1") the problem is with the formatting of the request and not with how the request is created. 


That said I'll upload the code I used. I was doing my testing in bash for simplicity purposes to get the request syntax correct and then porting it over to the Arduino (in C) once I was sure I knew what I was doing.

Comment: You should make sure that the server actually supports chunked data, and that it is turned on. Also at the end aren't you supposed to have a blank line? `\r\n\r\n`